# How to set up download path of Epub file

Tags: download, path, directory, epub

- How can I set up my epub book (I made it) to be download to other folder than download folder on Android phone?.
- Maybe to be downlaoader to folder where Kobo reader keeps Epub files?
- Can i do than in manifest file?

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: I made epub book and I want to sell this book on my site. When customer pay epub book He / She can download epub book with phone. Downloaded Epub is saved on downlaod folder of the phone. Can I somehow set epub manifest or other file to downloaded book be saved in other folder than "download folder"?

Comment: It is better if you move the comment above directly into the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you cannot control from within your EPUB file where it is going to be downloaded on the filesystem of a particular device. (For example, on iOS there is no user-accessible filesystem, and EPUB is just a document format, like PDF or ODT!)

Where an EPUB file, once downloaded, ends up depends on which apps are available on the user's device.

For example, certain apps might register a suitable Intent and be able to "intercept" the EPUB file when you click the download link in the browser: once the download is completed, they might "move" the downloaded file into their app storage directory. Other apps might register an Intent telling Android that they can "open" EPUB files, but the app itself will not manage the download and file move, likely resulting in the EPUB file to be downloaded in the "Download" directory.

If you control the Web server from which users will download the EPUB file, you can make sure to set the appropriate MIME Type (served by the Web server) for the .epub file. See e.g. this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types